# Cordova iPhone 6 / 6+ Splashscreen images

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

maybe it's just a simple question: Where can i found the Splashscreenimages for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+?

Everytime i build a project, i can't find the images for those iPhones. Are they still not available over Cordova and have to be created by myself, or do i overlook sth?

I have these Images in my Folder, is there a feature like upscaling them?

[image]

i hope you can help me!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cordova platform add ios@master --usegit
```

fixed my problem and installed all the thinks i need incl. the new splashscreens